# How do I change the type of a variable in Angular

Tags: angular

I use  `{{product.price.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})}}`

To display the price in my view. It was working when I was manualy typing the value in the array in Angular.

Now I am fetching the database to fill the product array.

The price field is of Type `INT`

The database result are fed to angular trought an ajax request and json encoded

The price is displayed but not the $CA after it. I think the function is not seeing this value as an `Number­`.

This is the function a use to get all my product data.

```
sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
       this.productList=productList;
    });
}
```

Then the angular view

```
<app-product data-ng-init="sendGetRequest()" (productAdded)="addProductToCart($event)" [products]="productList"> </app-product>
```

The actual data being diplayed

```
<section *ngFor="let product of products" >
      <div >
        {{product.model}}
        <br>
        <div class="preView"><img src="./assets/{{product.img}}"></div>
        {{product.price.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})}}<br>
        <button (click)="addProductToCart(product)">+</button><br>
      </div>
  </section>
```

So i'm not sure where and how i should work with the type.

If I change my function to;

```
  sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
       this.productList=productList.map(product=>{
        product.price = +product.price; // cast to number
        return product;
      });
    });
```

}

I'm getting a warning ;

Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object

But visual studio offers a quickfix so I have tryed it and now my code looks like;

```
 private _productList: any;
  public get productList(): any {
    return this._productList;
  }
  public set productList(value: any) {
    this._productList = value;
  }

  sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
       this.productList=productList.map(product=>{
        product.price = +product.price; // cast to number
        return product;
      });
    });
}
```

Now it is working but I still get an error for the map;

ERROR in src/app/store/store.component.ts:28:37 - error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
28        this.productList=productList.map(product=>{
```

Here is an image of my screen

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList)=>{
    this.productList=productList.map(product=>{
        product.price = +product.price; // cast to number
        return product;
      });
   });
}
```

you just need to cast it to number.
you are receiving string type price.

Comment: I get ;
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object' Even if i declare 
productList : any;

Comment: I have edited my question with more info. Even if it's working i still get an error in visual studio

Comment: private _productList: any;  make it public or default. and its productList not _productList.
can you please share ur subscribed productList by console.log

Comment: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "1", model: "Car-Go", price: 210, img: "MilitaryCargo.jpg", reg_date: "2020-04-09 14:23:38"}
1: {id: "2", model: "ready-1", price: 145, img: "ReadyOne.jpg", reg_date: "2020-04-09 14:23:38"}
2: {id: "3", model: "Red Cross", price: 180, img: "RedCross.jpg", reg_date: "2020-04-09 14:23:38"}
3: {id: "4", model: "Organic Bathing Kit", price: 89, img: "bath.jpg", reg_date: "2020-04-09 14:23:38"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: This output gets printed ou 4 times i dont know why

Comment: everything is seems to be good.can you please check it again after restart visual studio

Comment: Ok this is weird. If i restart visual i get the error and nothing is working. if i add a space and save the file i get no error and its working. If i remove the space and save i get the error but it is still working.

Comment: I have added an screen shot of my code and the error if you see anything. I dont understand the behavior of this error.

Comment: can you please try  `sendGetRequest(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost/ajax.php').subscribe((productList : [])=>{ and here
       console.log(Array.isArray(productList)); // change is here
       this.productList=productList.map(product=>{
        product.price = +product.price; // cast to number
        return product;
      });
    });
}`
and let me know the result of new log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211311/discussion-between-madeindreams-and-azizul-hoq).